# Gráfico de Linha Personalizado - qualquer ferramenta

Tags: python, r, microsoft-excel, gráfico, graphics

Preciso criar um gráfico de linhas (python, R ou até excel), onde cada linha é uma categoria de produtos, o eixo y é a venda e o x é o tempo. Se a venda estiver acima da meta, a linha fica de uma cor, já se tiver abaixo, outra cor. Seria uma maneira de no gráfico de linhas temporal eu mostrar se aquela categoria está acima ou abaixo da meta no período todo.

Comment: Hey, eu não sei fazer o gráfico puxando os dados do banco em python, mas você pode puxar os dados do banco através do python e colocar elas em um gráfico em javascript.

Comment: https://www.highcharts.com/demo/line-basic O Highcharts tem gráficos bonitos e fáceis de serem manipulados.

Comment: Infelizmente, esta pergunta não pode ser reproduzida por quem for tentar respondê-la. Por favor, [dê uma olhada neste link](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/824/como-criar-um-exemplo-m%c3%adnimo-reproduz%c3%advel-em-r) e veja como fazer uma pergunta reproduzível em R. Assim, as pessoas que desejarem te ajudar conseguirão fazer isto da melhor maneira possível.

Comment: Seja bem-vindo(a). Por favor faça o [tour], depois leia [Como devemos formatar perguntas e respostas?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1084/como-devemos-formatar-perguntas-e-respostas) e crie um [mcve] para a pergunta. Pois a pergunta está muito ampla e quando [você é mais específico](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1481/75104), há mais chances de sua pergunta ser respondida corretamente.

Answer (score 1):

Difícil responder com poucas informações, mas segue uma tentativa

```
#os dados
set.seed(123)
tss=abs(matrix(rnorm(50*3,1000,1000),ncol=3))
meta=colMeans(tss)*c(0.8,1.2,1.4) # suposto
mcol=apply(tss-meta,2,function(vx)ifelse(vx>=0,"Sup.Meta","Inf.Meta"))

library(ggplot2)
library(reshape)

tssdf=data.frame(tss)
tssdf$data=1:nrow(tssdf)
#melt(mcol)
tssdfm=melt(tssdf, id = "data")
tssdfm$supmeta=factor(melt(mcol)$value)

ggplot(data=tssdfm, aes(x=data, y=value, colour=variable))  +theme_bw() + geom_line()+
  geom_point(aes(col=supmeta), size=3)
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]